# Mongo - Remove Array Element with $pull Does Not Work With $nin (does not exist)

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have the following query and it works with $in but not with $nin.
I'm trying to remove the link list items by name (itemA and itemB) from all records that are NOT part of a document that has a user name which contains '@not_these' or '@nor_these'.

```
db.users.update({userName:{$nin: [ RegExp('@not_these.com'), RegExp('@nor_these.com') ]}},{$pull:{'myLinkList': {name: {$in: ['itemA', 'itemB']} } } } )
```

If I make it $in and and declare the RegExp() explicitly it does remove the array items as expected.

```
db.users.update({userName:{$in: [ RegExp('@yes_these.com'), RegExp('@and_these.com') ]}},{$pull:{'myLinkList': {name: {$in: ['itemA', 'itemB']} } } } )
```

This one does remove itemA and itemB array list items for those explicitly declared users.
Why can't the items '@yes_these' and '@and_these' be removed using the first example? It seems to do nothing when executed.

Sample document:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId('5e34741aa18d8a0c24078b61'),
"myLinkList": [
    {
        "name": "item",
        "created": ISODate('2020-01-31T18:38:18.682Z'),
        "managedBy": [
            "imm"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "itemA",
        "created": ISODate('2020-01-31T18:38:18.682Z'),
        "managedBy": [
            "imm"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "itemB",
        "created": ISODate('2020-01-31T18:38:18.682Z'),
        "managedBy": [
            "imm"
        ]
    }
],
"userName": "@yes_these.com"
}
```

After update (hopefully):

```
{
"_id": ObjectId('5e34741aa18d8a0c24078b61'),
"myLinkList": [
    {
        "name": "item",
        "created": ISODate('2020-01-31T18:38:18.682Z'),
        "managedBy": [
            "imm"
        ]
    }
],
"userName": "@yes_these.com"
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample document with before/after data?

Comment: yes added sample

Comment: The after would be without the last two myLinkList items.

Comment: This is using MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4

Answer (score 1):

I verified this did work:

```
db.users.updateMany({userName:{$nin: [ /@not_these\.com/), /@nor_these\.com/) ]}},{$pull:{'myLinkList': {name: {$in: ['itemA', 'itemB']} } } } )
```